# How to get the input order of parameters in JCommander?

Tags: java, jcommander

How can I get the input order of parameters in JCommander?
I want to know which parameter was input first.
For example

```
Myapp --cut -- reverse
Myapp --reverse -- cut
```

Is this possible in Jcommander?
And if so, how?

Comment: The question should be clear by now. An answer is open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve your need is instead of define multiple flag.

See [Arities (multiple values for parameters)](https://jcommander.org/#_arities_multiple_values_for_parameters)

Then read your command args:

```
@Parameter(names = "-cmd", variableArity = true)
public List<String> commands= new ArrayList<>();

MyApp -cmd cut reverse -anotherCmd
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I can use it but then I think I can't show the options with usage(). I have to do some further reading on Jcommander.